# PHP: Find empty value in array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to display an error if one of the `<input>` boxes the user has submitted is empty, but I also want to process the boxes that do not have empty names.

Here is the form: http://jsfiddle.net/Draven/rEPXM/27/

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['addFolder']))
{    
    foreach($_POST['folder'] as $id => $value)
    {
        $database->query('INSERT INTO folders (name) VALUES (?)', array($value));
    }
    $success[] = "Folder(s) added";                 
}
```

Comment: `var_dump($folder) before if(!empty($folder))`. What you get?

Comment: @insertusernamehere I am using PDO, I don't need to sanitize.

Comment: @zarkoz I added two input boxes, the first one had a name "TEst", the second one was empty. `array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "TEst" [1]=> string(0) "" }`

Comment: Ah OK, didn't see that. Deleted my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try as below

```
foreach($folder as $id => $value)
{
    if($value){
      $database->query('INSERT INTO folders (name) VALUES (?)', array($value));
    }
    else {
       $error[]=$id;
    }
}
```

$error contains all indexes which doesn't have value.

Comment: This'll work. I'll leave out giving an error. Might confuse people anyway. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$folder = isset($_POST['folder']) && is_array($_POST['folder'])
        ? $_POST['folder']
        : array();
$errors = array();
foreach ($folder as $id => $value) {
    $value = is_array($value) ? '' : trim($value);
    if ($value == '') {
        $errors[$id] = 'Empty value';
        continue;
    }

    $database->query('INSERT INTO folders (name) VALUES (?)', array($value));
}
```

Edit your template:

```
...

<div id="foldercontainer">
<?php foreach ($errors as $error): ?>
    <div>
        <div><?php echo $error ?></div>
        <input name="folder[]" type="text" size="20" value="" />
    </div>
<?php endforeach ?>
</div>

...
```

Answer (score 0):

`if(!isset($folder) || $folder === "")`

But I do not understand whyyou are running the query if you if `$folder` is empty...

Comment: That won't process the boxes that DO have names. My code probably confused you. I'll take out my check.

Comment: I don't understand. If this condition is true, don't do the query. Or just negate the expression if you want to do it the opposite way.

Answer (score 0):

Complementing what was said.
Use trim() when you want to test if a value is empty. You do not want to name folders with empty values, right?​​:

```
$folder = array('aaaa', 'bbbb', ' ', '    ');

foreach($folder as $id => $value) {
    $value = trim($value);

    if(!empty($value)) {
      var_dump($value);
    } else {
       $error[]=$id;
    }
}
```

On the way up the output will be:

```
string 'aaaa' (length=4)

string 'bbbb' (length=4)
```

Now, without using trim() and test if it is not empty, the output is(and it is a mistake):

```
string 'aaaa' (length=4)

string 'bbbb' (length=4)

string ' ' (length=1)

string '    ' (length=4)
```